# Fortran don't allow variable value to change

Tags: fortran, subroutine, variable-declaration

Is there any way to force a variable to be constant even if a subroutine (part of a standard library) tries to change it? Obviously `intent(in)` throws an error.

Comment: What do you want to happen when the other subroutine tries to change the value?  It's ignored (the variable remains unchanged in that subroutine); there's an error (run-time or compile-time); the change is used in that subroutine but is reverted, back in your program?

Comment: I would avoid modifying the source of a "standard library" and actually make a copy to pass to the subroutine.

Comment: The change is used in the subroutine but is reverted, back in my program.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pass a copy of the variable to the library.

Or pass to your subroutine by `VALUE` instead of `INTENT(IN)`. It will be changed, but only inside your own subroutine.

Comment: For clarity, you mean "have the `value` attribute on the dummy argument"?

Comment: Yes, on the dummy argument istead of the intent(in).